# How Do I Trim Leading and Trailing Quote from MySQL Row?

Tags: mysql, database, trim

I have a MySQL table that I have imported from a CSV file.  In this process, a bunch of the entries have quote marks leading and trailing the entry of several data rows.  For example the the table 'example_table' I have a row called 'title.'  Some of these titles are written as:

```
"title1"
"title2"
"title3"
```

and some are written without the quote marks:

```
title4
title5
title6
```

I have tried a variety of SQL calls to trim the row but I keep getting errors.  Here is my sql call:

```
SELECT * FROM `example_table` TRIM(LEADING '"' FROM "title")
```

This is the error from MySQL when I run the call:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

How do I go about getting rid of all the trailing and leading quotation marks from the row?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE `example_table` 
   SET `title` = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM `title`)
```

This query will updated your `example_table` to remove leading and trailing double quotes from the value of the `title` column.

If you don't want to update the table, but want to fetch the rows with double quotes removed, then use @Sam Dufel's answer.

Comment: The other methods worked for changing the values, but your answer actually updates the table which is what I needed.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

Just change that to

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM title) AS trimmed_title FROM `example_table`
```

Comment: how to trim all the columns without specifying the column name?

Answer (score 8):

This solved my problem

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name,'"','')
```

Comment: This method may also delete the quote in inner string.

Answer (score 6):

this works for me

```
select trim(both '"' from column_name) from table_name;
```

Comment: this solution works!
but how can I trim all the columns without specifying the column name?