# Could someone show me an example of the trim command in mysql

Tags: trim

I want to trim (both left and right, and I know if I leave it unselected it will trim left and right by default) on a table named my_contacts. I just don't understand the string length, leading (I want to get rid of white spaces on the left most of all) and the text book is very vague, If I had an example to look at I think I could figure it out.

```
update * trim?????
from my_contacts
where
```

thanks

Comment: trim(both ' ' from '%') seems to be close but...its giving me a syntax err under the word trim, and I know I need to tell it what table but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: update my_contacts
rtrim(both ' ' from '%');        and this gives me a syntax err under the open paren...

Comment: I gave you a -1 because you can get your answer by [looking at the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), which has many examples.

Comment: +1 to counter @BurhanKhalid's -1. OP indicated that he had consulted a textbook and got some understanding of the function before posting and is not simply begging for help.

Comment: @dwurf thank you, I have looked on the web and in my textbook, and as you can see by what I have posted I do get some of it. Programming textbooks are very vague to a non programmer

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, next time please read the entire post. I am not looking for someone to do my homework for me (I am enrolled in a course at the moment) but my teacher is very non responsive to his students, does not answer emails etc. I am sure you have been doing this for years, and I can also state without a doubt that there are skills that I have (like building a house or welding) that you don't and I would never belittle or look down upon someone for not knowing something and trying to learn it!

Comment: You asked for examples. The documentation provides many examples. Your book maybe unclear, that's fine - you never indicated that you checked the documentation and you still couldn't understand the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example (untested, sqlfiddle is down ):

```
create table my_contacts (
    id integer not null primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

insert into my_contacts (name)
values ('Steve'), (' Mary'), ('Amy '), (' Susan ');

update my_contacts set name = trim(leading ' ' from name); -- left only
update my_contacts set name = trim(name); -- left and right
```

See also [How Do I Trim Leading and Trailing Quote from MySQL Row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718713/how-do-i-trim-leading-and-trailing-quote-from-mysql-row)

Answer (score 0):

update my_contacts set email = trim(leading ' ' from email);
update my_contacts set status = trim(both ' ' from status);  etc..............thank you so much DWURF *now that I see the entire line of code*, NOW  I get it, thanks! Sometimes that's all it takes, honestly some people on this site are very critical and some are very helpful, believe me if I am asking what you may think to be a stupid question, its because I have been doing sql for all of about a month!